# Draw a label in a colored area with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a colored area obtained with a plot with filledcurves. I want to add a label in this area. The filled curve is transparent (set style fill transparent solid), yet my label is not visible (set label 1 "maximally 1^{st} order" at 0.2,0.8 textcolor 'red'). Is there a way to draw the label *after* the data ?

Comment: Please add example of your code to the question.

Comment: Use `set label ... front`, which will draw your label on top of the other elements in the graph.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I should have read more carefully the F. manual !!!

Comment: @miguel may be you can make that an answer :)